# what will happen if PIG process 1 TB of data with default setting?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

i read that PIG will assign the number of reducers based on the input file size. For each GB a reducer would be allocated and the maximum will be of 999 reducers which is default.(**i know it can be changed in *pig.exec.reducers.max***).what will happen or how the reducers will be allocated if i process a TB of data with a default setting?

Answer (score 1):

The number of reducers you get is dependent on the number you choose or a basic formula is used (see below).  You can set this by running `SET default_parallel 20;` for example to set it to 20.  See http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html#set

`pig.exec.reducers.max` is simply an upper bound.  If you do not explicitly set the number of reducers, the following formula is used `MIN (pig.exec.reducers.max, total input size (in bytes) / bytes per reducer)` where bytes per reducer is set by `pig.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer` with a default of 1GB.